# ID of the First message LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a problem with Linq Expressions.
I have a datas of txt like this.

int day, int ID, string message

```
1 13
#abor# #e#tun###agy#szel#2# #o##h#d#g ##rkasn#o#oka# #a#tunk e####a#akn##$#$#$##$$$$$$####
1 19
ta###t##ertunk ##gy #zel#####ok hide##f#r##sn#omo#at ##ttu## e#y patak#al$#$$$$$###$$$$$$$
.............
```

- 

And I like to get the ID of the first message.
I tried like this:

```
public static void task2()
{
           IEnumerable<Expadatok> firstmessid = Expadat.First(x => x.message).ID;
           Expadatok firstmessid = Expadat.First(x => x.message).ID;

           Console.WriteLine($"The ID of the first massage was {firstmessid}");
}
```

but none of them worked.
Data read was successful, What did I wrong?

Comment: And Expadat.First().ID ?

Comment: Please add info on how these messages end up in `Expadat` and what  `Expadat` looks like. Also, what's the meaning of "none of them worked"? Exceptions? If so, show the exception message(s).

Comment: It is a list `private static List<Expadatok> Expadat = new List<Expadatok>();` It says cannot implicity  convert type 'string ' to 'bool' for the x.message

Comment: That implies you wll never get any output because `Expadat` is empty. How do you transform the text into `Expadatok`?

Comment: It is not empty, I made a constructor and I uploaded the list with the txt data through a method.

Answer (score 0):

There is no information on what is Expadat, Expadatok ... and also what does First(x => x.message) might mean (message is a string, no? Used in a context where there should be a boolean expression).

This works fine:

```
void Main()
{
    var plain = s.Split(new char[] { '\n', '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var data = plain
        .Where((p, i) => i % 2 == 0)
        .Select(p => p.Split())
        .Select(p => new {Day=p[0], ID=p[1]})
        .Zip(plain.Where((p, i) => i % 2 == 1), (f, s) => new {Day = f.Day, ID=f.ID,Message=s});
    
    Console.WriteLine(data.First(x => x.Message).Message);
}

string s = @"1 13
#abor# #e#tun###agy#szel#2# #o##h#d#g ##rkasn#o#oka# #a#tunk e####a#akn##$#$#$##$$$$$$####
1 19
ta###t##ertunk ##gy #zel#####ok hide##f#r##sn#omo#at ##ttu## e#y patak#al$#$$$$$###$$$$$$$";
```

Answer (score 0):

`Expadat.First(x => x.message)` does *not* mean "get the first message from Expadat", but "get the first item from Expadat where the message property is 'true' ". And as `message` is of type `string`, that's a compiler error ("cannot implicity convert type 'string' to 'bool' ").

What you probably want is

```
Expadat.First().ID
```

meaning: get the first item from Expadat, and then use its ID property.

Note that `.First()` will fail if Expadat is empty. You could use `.FirstOrDefault()`, but that will return a `null` when the list is empty - leading to a NullReferenceException when you try to access its ID property.